# Transform a plot/graphics from one coordinates to another?

Tags: plotting, graphics, coordinate-transformation

I wonder if it is possible to transform plot/graphics from one coordinate system to another in `Mathematica`.
To be more specific we can consider some plot in $(r,\theta)$ spherical coordinates ($\varphi =0$).

```
VectorPlot[{0, \[Theta]}, {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}, {r, 0, 5}]
```

Which is, ofcourse, just a plot of constant $\theta$.

[image]

Now If we would transform this into cartesian coordinates $x,y$ this should look like

[image]

Can we do this without transforming the field? The reason I need this is because I'm working with imported graphics.

Note that the second picture was produced by

```
TransformedField["Polar" -> "Cartesian", {0, \[Theta]}, {r, \[Theta]} -> {x, y}]
StreamPlot[%, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}]
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me what transformation you are after - do you want to transform stream plots into different coordinate systems, or vector plots? (Note that the arrows drawn in the two cases have different meanings)

Comment: The things is that I want any graphics, that's why the question is so vague. Please, if it is still not clear after this comment tell me and I will close the question a try to formulate it in a different way.

Comment: The problem is that the "correct" result depends on what the elements of the graphic mean: For a vector plot, the arrows show the value of a function at the starting point of the vector. For a stream plot, the arrow follows the underlying vector field. (You can swap `VectorPlot`/`StreamPlot` in your two examples to see how the two are transformed differently)

Comment: Oh ok. Thank you for your answer.
I will close the question.

Answer (score 0):

You may change the coordinates of the arrows directly in the plot. However, this does not change the PlotRange as in your example.

To change the arrows, you can use "ReplaceAll" like:

```
vp = VectorPlot[{0, \[Theta]}, {\[Theta], 0, \[Pi]}, {r, 0, 5}];
vp /. Arrow[{p1_List, p2_}] :> Arrow[{p1, p1 + 0.2 {-p1[[2]], p1[[1]]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think this answer the problem. The concrete example what I gave was just an example, I want to do this for any 2D plot/graphics. But thank you anyway.

Comment: p1 gives you the starting position of the arrow, the end position is given by the field you have.